# Selecting records by SQL Query and saving SUM or COUNT result into differnt table

Tags: arcpy, sql, query

I am trying to create a python toolbox with the following function:
I want to select points or lines within a polygon and save the selected feautres as a temporarily Feature. (That works)

Then I want to use SQL-Queries for example to count all Features of the Point-Feature-Class or the total length of a Line-Feature-Class. The result of the queries should be written into an existing Table. For example the result of the total length of a Line-Feature-Class, should be written into the Field: TOTAL_LENGTH.

At the end, the Table should be exported as an excel-file (Should be no problem)

I don't want to get the complete finished code. Just an Idea how to do the query and saving the result into a different existing table.

Does somebody has an idea?

Comment: If I understand the ask, Summary Statistics could help (though not via SQL): http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Richard is right about Summary Statistics being your best bet, but if for some reason you don't want to do that:

1: Select by location (you say this already works)

2: For point feature class:

```
    count = int(str(arcpy.GetCount_management))
```

2: For line feature class:

```
    total_len = 0
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line_fc, "SHAPE_Length"):
        total_len+=row[0]
```

3:

```
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_fc, "StatField") as inserter:
        #StatField will be count or length dep on point or line fc
        inserter.insertRow([count]) #Or total_len if line fc
```

4: TableToExcel_conversion tool

Comment: The SearchCursor can have a SQL query as a parameter in case you need to select certain records:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

Comment: Great! Glad it worked for you!